# how to display one of the 4 values in one label from a JSON link in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uilabel

I am doing one project now with JSON links.

In that, leaves for employees are given as casual-5, emergency-2, vacation-3, medical-0.

In JSON link it is given seperately.

```
"employee_casual_leave":0,"employee_medical_leave":0,"employee_annual_leave":0,"employee_emergency_leave":1
```

But in my code I have to get any one of them in one label. i.e. type of leave a person took should be displayed in a label.

I had put an label in xib and set my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as following:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cel";

    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section];

    NSUserDefaults *UserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [UserDefaults setObject:str forKey:@"leaveCount"];
    [UserDefaults synchronize];

    cell1=[self.tab1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell1==nil) {
        NSArray*toplevelobject=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"emp_leave_list" owner:self options:nil];
        cell1=[toplevelobject objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *s7=[[[Dict1  objectForKey:@"employee_list"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section ]objectForKey:@"employee_other_leave"]  ;

    NSString *s700= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", s7];

    cell1.leave_type.text=s7;

    return  cell1;
}
```

In the label "leave_type" I want to display the type of leave the employee took whether its casual or emergency or others or vacation. Please give me an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: first add complete json here and format your code.

Comment: any one knows answer for my question?

Comment: Add your complete json response

Comment: example:
"employee_list": [{
"employee_medical_leave": 0,
"employee_annual_leave": 0,
"employee_emergency_leave": 5”}]}

Comment: What is it not working ??

Answer (score 0):

1) Parse json in method and declare a array in YourViewController.h file

```
 NSMutableArray *arrEmployee;

 -(void)getEmployeeDetail:(NSDictionary *)jsonResponse
 {
       arrEmployee = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"employee_list"];
       [yourTable reloadData];
}
```

2) Add tableview delegate

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
    }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return arrEmployee.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier"];

    NSDictionary *info = [arrEmployee objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblLeave = [info objectForKey:@"employee_annual_leave"];

    return cell;
}
```